# Matplotlib doesn't show hatches in custom legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, patch, legend, handles

I create a custom legend, but he does not show the hatches of the patches. Whats wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Patch
from pylab import *
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)
fig1 = plt.figure(1,(10,10))
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
far_patch = Patch(color=[168/256,175/256,175/256], label='Farshore')
near_patch = Patch(color=[168/256,175/256,175/256], label='Nearshore',     hatch ='o')
legend=plt.legend(handles=[far_patch, near_patch],loc='upper left',     handlelength=1, handleheight=1,labelspacing=0,    fontsize=8,borderaxespad=0.3,handletextpad=0.2)

frame = legend.get_frame()
frame.set_edgecolor('none')

figureName='test'

plt.savefig(figureName+'.pdf',bbox_inches='tight',dpi=fig1.dpi)
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: please provide a minimal working example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The color keyword from the `Patch` object will override both the facecolor and the edgecolor. So its propably showing the hatch correctly, but in the same color as the patch. Specifically setting the `facecolor` will solve it, and the `edgecolor` can be used to color the hatch.

So try:

```
near_patch = Patch(facecolor=[168/256,175/256,175/256], 
                   label='Nearshore', hatch ='o')
```

[image]

You can set the `linewidth` to zero if you only want to see the hatch.